# Updating associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

I have lesson model that has many transcripts in different languages.
I want to process each transcript and give it a title.
I am unable to debug the code inside the each block, I am getting into the collection proxy class. What is the right way to do this?

My code:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lesson_transcripts
```

In the update method of controller:

```
def update
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :update, @lesson
  @lesson.attributes = params[:lesson]

  @lesson.lesson_transcripts.each do |t|
    t.title = ...
  end
  @lesson.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your Lesson model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :lesson_transcripts
```

Then, in your controller, you can simply have:

```
def update
  @lesson = Lesson.find params[:id]
  authorize! :update, @lesson

  @lesson.update_attributes params[:lessons]
end
```

Hope this helps.